# Symfony2: how to render form submit separately

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm creating a form in Symfony2 that contains more than one submit button. I need to control where these buttons are rendered. I tried the following, but naturally nothing happens.

```
    <h1>Search Form</h1>
    <div id="search_form">
        {{ form(formSearch) }}
    </div>
    <div id="search_tasks">
        Tasks: 
        {{ form_widget(formSearch.searchButton1) }}
        {{ form_widget(formSearch.searchButton2) }}
    </div>
```

The search buttons are declared in the form class; they are rendered inside `#search_form` and nothing shows up in `#search_tasks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already rendering the whole form with `{{ form(formSearch) }}` (fields and buttons are only rendered once).

You need to render the start, rows and end separately.

```
{{ form_start(formSearch) }}
    <h1>Search Form</h1>
    <div id="search_form">
        {{ form_row(formSearch.field1) }}
        {{ form_row(formSearch.field2) }}
        {{ form_row(formSearch.field3) }}
    </div>
    <div id="search_tasks">
        Tasks: 
        {{ form_widget(formSearch.searchButton1) }}
        {{ form_widget(formSearch.searchButton2) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(formSearch) }}
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there a way to render multiple/all fields instead of one per row manually? The fields will are subject to occasional change so they can't be hardcoded.

Comment: You could use `{% for child in form %}` but then you would come into the same issues as above. The best bet would be to check whether the field is defined and then print that like `{% if form.field is defined %}{{ form_row(form.field) }}{% endif %}`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue where I needed my Submit and Reset buttons to be on the same row.  My forms are dynamic so there was no way I could output the fields individually.  I captured the buttons' HTML first so that `form_widget(form)` wouldn't output them for me.

```
{% form_theme form 'AppBundle::form/form_layout.html.twig' %}

<div class="row">

        {{ form_start(form) }}

        {% if form.submit is defined %}
                {% set submitButton = form_widget(form.submit) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if form.reset is defined %}
                {% set resetButton = form_widget(form.reset) %}
        {% endif %}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <div class="form-group row">                
                {% if submitButton is defined %}
                        {{ submitButton|raw }}
                {% endif %}
                {% if resetButton is defined %}
                        {{ resetButton|raw }}
                {% endif %}
        </div>

        {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```